# How can I write a function in python that when an agent makes a move, in its next move it cannot make the reverse move

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Agent1 is making moves by moving a tile which contains either the number 1 or 2 and Agent2 is making moves by moving a tile containing the number 8 or 9. The two agents are in a 3x3 board environment like 8 tile puzzle.
I want to write a function that when Agent1 makes a move, the next move of Agent1 cannot be the reverse move from the previous move so Agent1 cannot place the number two the tile where the number initially was. The same goes for Agent2

I thought of something like:

```
move = Agent1 moves tile 1
if Agent1 moves tile with number 1(at whatever index it is currently):
   next.move Agent 1 != reverse.move
else:
    print(False)
```

Comment: This question is rather general. So the general answer is: Remember the last move of each agent and check that it doesn't try to make the reverse move next.

Comment: Yeah what is the code for that in Python?

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: to get Python code for this first you would have to show your Python code - current code is not real Python.

Comment: normally it need first set `previous_pos = None` at start, next check `if pos_after_move == previous_pos: print("WRONG") else: previous_pos = current_pos `